# 1045 Error for MySQL database account I created

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just created a user account for myself to access *only* the MariaDB database I just created ("publications") using XAMPP on a Windows 10 PC.

I did this by using the code at the end of this post.

I then try to sign into the database by using this path and command in the command prompt:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u steve -p
```

It then prompts me for a password, but when I enter the password I get the error

```
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'steve'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

I know the password is correct because I created it.

Note that this is NOT a root-level password; it should only work for the "publications" database.

Strangely, I can just bypass the password requirement by hitting "enter," but I want access to this database to be password-protected, but when I DO enter the password, I get the error!

Why am I getting this error?  Do I need to reset my password? If so, how?

Thanks!

Code I entered:

```
GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'steve@localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 1):

After you entered command:

```
mysql>GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'steve'@'localhost';
```

Then flush:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Try login again.

Note: make sure you created an user as follow command:

```
CREATE USER 'steve'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
```

and note:

```
'steve@localhost'
```

or

```
'steve'@'localhost'
```

on `GRANT ALL` command

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is only needed when modifying the `mysql.*` tables directly. Right after a `GRANT` it is a no-op as `GRANT` takes care of flushing itself already.

The "make sure @ is not enclosed by quotes" part is valid though.

A quick `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` should show if there's a correct steve/localhost entry, or one with "steve@localhost" as username and no host ...

Comment: Thanks so much Mr. Holzgraefe!  The "SELECT user" lookup did the trick.  Indeed I didn't enter my username correctly (wrapped the whole thing in a single set of quotes).